# paths are not working in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to simplify my import paths so that I can get rid of deeply nested paths. I'm using React with typescript so I edit my tsConfig file in this way,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

The problem is when I try to import any file from src it says module not found.

```
import app from "App"
```

where App is a directory that contains index.ts

Comment: Is not that easy, it depends on your react configuration as well, if you're using react create app you can eject it to be able to make aliases or you could use the library called craco as well if you don't want to eject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add @/ before steric.

```
"paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
```